# Flattening a nested JSON using jolt transform - Very complex

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex nested JSON using jolt transformation. Input and output detail is given below.

Input

```json
[
  {
    "metadata": {
      "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z"
    },
    "payload": [
      {
        "plant": "0DE1",
        "store": "",
        "t_objectandcharvalcomb": [
          {
            "productalloccharacteristic01": "0DE1",
            "productalloccharacteristic02": "30",
            "productalloccharacteristic03": "FC",
            "productalloccharacteristic04": "#",
            "t_time_series_consumption": [
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-04",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              },
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-05",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "plant": "0DE1",
        "store": "",
        "t_objectandcharvalcomb": [
          {
            "productalloccharacteristic01": "0DE1",
            "productalloccharacteristic02": "30",
            "productalloccharacteristic03": "LT",
            "t_time_series_consumption": [
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-04",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              },
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-05",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "plant": "0DE1",
        "store": "",
        "t_objectandcharvalcomb": [
          {
            "productalloccharacteristic01": "0DE1",
            "productalloccharacteristic02": "30",
            "productalloccharacteristic03": "PP",
            "productalloccharacteristic04": "#",
            "t_time_series_consumption": [
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-04",
                "startdateofprodallocconsump": "2023-09-04",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              },
              {
                "startdateofproductallocperd": "2023-09-05",
                "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpopenqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpassigqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqty": 0,
                "prodallocconsumpqtyunit": "EA"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output Expected

```json
[
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "FC",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-04",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  },
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "FC",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-05",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  },
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "LT",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-04",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  },
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "LT",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-05",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  },
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "PP",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-04",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  },
  {
    "event_time": "2023-09-04T08:46:15.0842Z",
    "Plant": "0DE1",
    "Store": "",
    "Location": "0DEA",
    "Distribution_Channel": "#",
    "Packing_type": "PP",
    "Product_Division": "",
    "Date": "2023-09-05",
    "Planned_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_Capacity_qty": 0,
    "Negative_open_qty": 0,
    "Consumed_assign_qty": 0
  }
]
```

Jolt spec which i m using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "*": {
            "t_objectandcharvalcomb": {
              "*": {
                "t_time_series_consumption": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(6,metadata.event_time)": "[&1].event_time",
                    "@(4,plant)": "[&1].Plant",
                    "@(4,store)": "[&1].Store",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic01)": "[&1].Location",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic02)": "[&1].Distribution_Channel",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic03)": "[&1].Packing_type",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic04)": "[&1].Product_Division",
                    "startdateofproductallocperd": "[&1].Date",
                    "productallocquantity": "[&1].Planned_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpopenqty": "[&1].Consumed_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": "[&1].Negative_open_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpassigqty": "[&1].Consumed_assign_qty"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But its not coming as expected.

Pls help Can anyone who is a jolt expert, help me get the desired output. I think i m stuck in the last step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add one more partition which might be provided by adding **&5** along with the current identifier **&1**, which has not to be nested within square brackets, such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "*": {
            "t_objectandcharvalcomb": {
              "*": {
                "t_time_series_consumption": {
                  "*": {
                    "@6,metadata.event_time": "&5_&1.event_time",
                    "@4,plant": "&5_&1.Plant",
                    "@4,store": "&5_&1.Store",
                    "@2,productalloccharacteristic01": "&5_&1.Location",
                    "@2,productalloccharacteristic02": "&5_&1.Distribution_Channel",
                    "@2,productalloccharacteristic03": "&5_&1.Packing_type",
                    "@2,productalloccharacteristic04": "&5_&1.Product_Division",
                    "startdateofproductallocperd": "&5_&1.Date",
                    "productallocquantity": "&5_&1.Planned_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpopenqty": "&5_&1.Consumed_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": "&5_&1.Negative_open_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpassigqty": "&5_&1.Consumed_assign_qty"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of the object keys
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": ""
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input has 3 payload objects, each with 2 t_time_series_consumption objects, and you want to generate 6 objects from them. Unfortunately in JOLT I don't believe there is a way to keep incrementing the output index when the internal objects have multiple fields. Using `[]` will keep incrementing the output index for each field you're trying to add, and neither the `payload` index nor the `t_time_series_consumption` indexes are correct, rather the correct output index is the `(payload index * 2) + t_time_series_consumption index`, which I don't believe you can represent in JOLT.

Instead if you put all the output fields into a single object, each field will contain an array of the correct size and values. Then you can iterate through each array and use that index to specify the output index. You can use the following spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "payload": {
          "*": {
            "t_objectandcharvalcomb": {
              "*": {
                "t_time_series_consumption": {
                  "*": {
                    "@(6,metadata.event_time)": "event_time",
                    "@(4,plant)": "Plant",
                    "@(4,store)": "Store",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic01)": "Location",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic02)": "Distribution_Channel",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic03)": "Packing_type",
                    "@(2,productalloccharacteristic04)": "Product_Division",
                    "startdateofproductallocperd": "Date",
                    "productallocquantity": "Planned_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpopenqty": "Consumed_Capacity_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpnegopenqty": "Negative_open_qty",
                    "prodallocconsumpassigqty": "Consumed_assign_qty"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "event_time": {
        "*": "[&].event_time"
      },
      "Plant": {
        "*": "[&].Plant"
      },
      "Store": {
        "*": "[&].Store"
      },
      "Location": {
        "*": "[&].Location"
      },
      "Distribution_Channel": {
        "*": "[&].Distribution_Channel"
      },
      "Packing_type": {
        "*": "[&].Packing_type"
      },
      "Product_Division": {
        "*": "[&].Product_Division"
      },
      "Date": {
        "*": "[&].Date"
      },
      "Planned_Capacity_qty": {
        "*": "[&].Planned_Capacity_qty"
      },
      "Consumed_Capacity_qty": {
        "*": "[&].Consumed_Capacity_qty"
      },
      "Negative_open_qty": {
        "*": "[&].Negative_open_qty"
      },
      "Consumed_assign_qty": {
        "*": "[&].Consumed_assign_qty"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

There might be a way to simplify the second shift spec but I couldn't figure out how/if to iterate over an object instead of an array. I could get the key names as values but couldn't figure out how to get them as key names in the output.